# Sequence of dates starting since 2015-01-01 until today

Tags: sql-server

I want to produce sequence of dates since given date until today using one select command. It is possible?

Comment: Yes its possible. What you have tried so far?

Comment: No idea. can you show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH DATES_CTE AS (
    SELECT TOP 100000
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1 AS DayNumber
    FROM
        sys.all_columns a
    CROSS JOIN
        sys.all_columns b)
SELECT
    DATEADD(DAY, DayNumber, 0) AS DateValue
FROM
    DATES_CTE
WHERE
    DATEADD(DAY, DayNumber, 0) >= '2016-01-01'
    AND DATEADD(DAY, DayNumber, 0) < '2016-05-01';
```

Comment: This solution is better as it allows to produce more than 100 rows

Answer (score 0):

Try this with CTE.

```
WITH CTE_DATE 
AS
(   SELECT  CONVERT(DATE,'2015-01-01') AS CDATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(DAY,1,CDATE)
    FROM    CTE_DATE
    WHERE   DATEADD(DAY,1,CDATE)    <=  GETDATE()
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_DATE
option (maxrecursion 0) -- for unlimited recursion
```

You can use the option `option (maxrecursion 0)` to avoid the limit recursion.

Comment: Recursive CTE's have a maximum recursion of 100, which will only allow you to get just over 3 months worth of dates.

Comment: @SeanPearce, No, we can set maxrecursion off option (maxrecursion 0) for unlimited loop. Result modified.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE #date (datevalues date) 

DECLARE @mindate DATE = '2015-01-01',
 @maxdate DATE = GETDATE()

WHILE @mindate <= @maxdate
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO
     #date (datevalues)
     SELECT @mindate 
     SELECT @mindate = dateadd(dd,1,@mindate)
END
GO
SELECT *FROM #date
GO
DROP TABLE #date
GO
```